# Get all-in on a steal by a deep stack with avg hand

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament, no-limit

I played a play money MTT on *Pokerstars* and was wondering about a *stealing* situation. I was already *In The (play) Money* but had a short stack, specifically **3.53 BB** with an **M of 2**.
My opponent was a very aggressive big stack of about **37 BB** and was on **BTN**, i was on **SB**.

Of course i was locked down only to all-in moves and that specific opponent raised anything so i was just searching *for any pair or any ace/king (with reasonable kicker) to call*.

I chose to re-raise *all-in* with Q♠T⋄ his latest raise and of course he called me down with A♠7♥ I lost the hand *(ace high)*, got out of tourney but i was wondering if the hand i had was enough for against a dude that had raised 3,4 times in a row, obviously milking the situation?

I mean, i know i had 2 orbits to wait **(M=2)** for something better but i didnt wanted to wait someone else to call him, i just grabbed the chance against an opponent that had junk most of the time he raised.

**It's Q♠T⋄ good enough of a hand to commit vs these kind of players (deep stacked aggros) who just goofing around with stealing, knowing that even if you have a *premium hand*, it's no big deal to them?**

Of course i know that **M=2 means play any 2 cards** but against this specific opponent who would call me *110%* of the time i was searching for something better. What would you play in my situation?

Comment: I'm confused about the action. You say you "call his latest raise" with QT but then you say he "called you down." Did you call all-in? Or did you raise and get called?

Comment: Either way, with a full table, 3.5 bigs, QT, and isolation against a loose-aggressive opponent, I'd take my chances with QT. You won't have any real fold equity, you're fortunate to be isolated against a single player, and you're lucky he enters pots with less than premium hands. Go for it, IMO.

Comment: @Chris Farmer, in this situation he raised the minimum (steal) and i just went all-in (_~3.5 BB_) and he called the rest. Table was folded to him and since the blinds (myself included) were shorts he just took the chance once again for what it may be _3,4 time in the row_. He couldn't have such good of a hand, could he ? I instantly thought i should loosen my reqs, not only because i'm about to enter twilight but because there may be my only chance to double-up. I didn't added BB in my thought, i realized that after big stack bet he should fold after my all-in as well. Thanx for the comment :)

Comment: You were 44% to win that hand with QT v A7, so that's not too bad. You're 48% against a random top 50% hand.  You're not likely to be isolated against a single player at any time in the next orbit, so taking your chances against a loose button raiser here was definitely the right thing, IMO.

Comment: @Chris Farmer, You're right, i concluded it's worth a try if you have _any_ 2 cards higher than aggressor's kicker (one card), thus close to coin-flip. Obviously _QTo_ falls into that category as well _K9o_ and an army of speculatives. I would throw away Q7o and below. It's good priced a chance of doubling-up with a hand that wins 44%+. Given the prize (doubling-up) any two medium-to-high cards should be profitable vs any random aggressor's cards.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer nice answer. Could you post it as an answer so it gets the attention and up votes it deserves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of things that come into play here:

1 - I think you need to clarify the action. Did you ***raise*** or did you go ***all-in***? There is a huge difference between those two actions, the latter makes your hand seem stronger than the former move. Your post says you just raised - what was the action after that?

2 - you have to look at it from his perspective. There is the "Rule of 10" - if you have someone out-chipped by a 10-1 ratio then you call their all-in with any two cards - seriously, ***any*** two cards. So, in many ways, your play does not matter. If he was following the Rule of 10, then he was just playing his role and he **should** have been calling you (and all the other short stacks) down. So maybe next time you want to raise against a smaller stack that might run away from a raise - this guy was **never** going to fold to you.

To me, it seems like the player you were up against understands the beauty (and madness!) of hold-em: any two cards can win. That's why the 10-1 Rule works, any two cards really aren't that big of a dog; even in the worst scenarios, like AA vs T2, AA will still lose about 12% of the time. I think your opponent acted as expected in this scenario.

Comment: thanx for the answer. I was quite sure that i edited my post to say _re-raised all-in_, thought i was wrong and it said only _re-raised_. Edited again, thanx. Yep, i know that _10-1 Harrington's rule_ :) and the aggressor took full advantage of it; this is why i needed to have better than avg cards, so the _QTo_ question rather _any face or T_; because he wouldn't fold and he just played with his stack but with more mediocre hands as well. Perhaps my post is confusing; i didn't want him to fold, merely to double-up by choosing a hand that stands more than avg than his hands.

Comment: @vlzvl oh sure, I understand the shove and I think that's a fine move. I'm going off your question and title and calling it a "steal". This was **never** going to work as a steal. When you're down to that few number of BB, you're really just hoping for small miracle, not much more.

Comment: i meant he tried to steal, not me :) Of course, i was about to enter dead zone, i'm living on miracles :) Still calling with junky hands like say _Q3o_ just reduces my chance about 10% and makes a huge impact against an aggro's typical hands.

Comment: @vlzvl understood. My mistake

Comment: no problem :) my question had all sorts of confusing parts :)